# How to trim multiple lines in a single string in PHP

Tags: php, regex, trim

How can I trim multiple lines in a single string?

I have this string:

```php
$string = 
'  Line 1  
Line 2       
    Line 3  '
;
```

And I want to transform it to be like this:

```php
$string =
'Line 1
Line 2
Line 3'
;
```

I am using this:

```php
echo implode("\n", array_map('trim', explode("\n", $string)));
```

And it works OK, but I was wondering if there´s a regex way, I tried a few and they didn't work.

Like:

```php
echo preg_replace("/ \n/", "\n", $string);
```

Still keeps the spaces.

Or

```php
echo preg_replace("/\s\n/", "\n", $string);
```

Screws all the string up.

This one seems promising..

```php
echo preg_replace("/[\s]+[\r\n]+/", "\n", $string);
```

Comment: Use `preg_replace("/^\h+|\h+$/m", "", $string);`

Comment: Remove any uninterrupted amount of spaces immediately after the start of the line, and any uninterrupted amount of spaces immediately before the end of the line. Using the "g" and "m" flags. `/^ *| *$/gm`

Answer (score 1):

Try this regular expression:

```
$string = 
'  Line 1  
Line 2       
    Line 3  '
;
echo $string;
echo "\n\n";
echo preg_replace("/^\s*([^\s].+)\s*$/Um", "$1", $string);
```

Outputs

```
  Line 1  
Line 2       
    Line 3  

Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
```

You can use very handy regex tester to construct and test your regex: https://regex101.com/

Comment: Note this solution will also get rid of blank lines before/after matching lines.